# if statement inside an if statement

Tags: python

this is kinda my homework and I'm stuck on making the code becoming a follow up question, like this code here, I've tried inserting an if statement after that but it gave me an unexpected incent error.

Here are my codes so far:

```
Choice = input("Hello! Do you want to buy or sell snakes? Please enter (b) or (s) :")
if Choice == "b":
    buySnake = input ("What snake do you want to buy? We are selling python, kingsnake, rattlesnake, deathadder, cobra, mamba, viper and gartersnake. Please choose one : ")
        if buySnake == "python":
             return (to be added)   
elif Choice == "s":
    sellFsnakes(snakeList,name,amount)
else:
    print("Please try again.")
    buyWsnakes(snakeList,name,amount)
```

Comment: If it says there's an unexpected indent, have you looked at that line's indentation and considered whether it could stand to be unindented at all?

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra indent. Just remove the extra level of indentation:

```
Choice = input("Hello! Do you want to buy or sell snakes? Please enter (b) or (s) :")
if Choice == "b":
    buySnake = input ("What snake do you want to buy? We are selling python, kingsnake, rattlesnake, deathadder, cobra, mamba, viper and gartersnake. Please choose one : ")
    if buySnake == "python":
        return (to be added)   
elif Choice == "s":
    sellFsnakes(snakeList,name,amount)
else:
    print("Please try again.")
    buyWsnakes(snakeList,name,amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is the way to create code blocks in Python. Your error says exactly what you did wrong.

```
if condition:
    # executes if condition is met
    if internalCondition:
        # executes if both condition and internalCondition is met
elif otherCondition:
    # executes if first statement didn't and otherCondition is met
else:
    # executes if nothing else executed
```

You indented `if internalCondition:` with excess whitespaces.